# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 ;

Tags: android, gradle, java-8

I m using this in gradle-properties:

```
**distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1- 
all.zip**
```

The build.gradle:

```
**buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
             //belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
             maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }**
```

I having this ERROR:

```
**failed org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
    org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
    org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
    org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0`enter code here`.1.pom'.
    org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.160.238] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**
```

I have updated the gradle.properties with gradle 5.6.4:

```
**distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
            distributionPath=wrapper/dists
            zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
            zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
            distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle- 
    5.6.4-all.zip**
```

And I have added maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in gradle repositories:

```
**buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; 
           //they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    allprojects{
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }**
```

I have set the proxies and set it  but the problem persisted.

Comment: @tomerpacific look a bit further down: `HttpHostConnectException: Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.160.238] failed: Connection timed out: connect`.  This is a connection failure.  Their internet connection is likely spotty, and they just need to try again.

Comment: (or otherwise figure out why the connection is failing)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be a bit more specific with the title of your question. Perhaps also read http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Comment: @RyanM My internet is working fine. I checked the toggle offline switch too, its online.

Comment: @japhungshar7 could you specify when does the error show? Is it when you try to use an IDE with a gradle project? Or running a specific gradle task from the command line? What OS are you using in your dev machine?

Comment: @XaviRigau this error is shown as i tried to sync my gradle project after creating one. (IDE with gradle project). The activity.xml file show "Design editor is unvailable after a successful sync". I m using windows 10 as my OS and virtual device nexus 6.

Comment: If the answer below didn't help you, I'm afraid I can't help more, sorry :(

Comment: @RyanM  yes you were right, that was due connection failure.

Answer (score 0):

Do try to use distribution url as:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

and in build.gradle :project:

```
   buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // add this line.

        }
        dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
             maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // add this line.

        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

You need to add  `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // add this line.`
in project build.gragle In order to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have tried doing all of the above as you said but still the problem is not resolved.

Comment: I have updated the answer please check. update class path as well with:  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'

Comment: did you added this line: maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }  please make sure internet is available in your system. Try to invalidated cache/ Restart then let me know if you are still getting the same error

Comment: yes, i haved added  maven { url "jitpack.io" }  in gradle repositories and my internet is working fine. I have also checked the offline toggle and had set it online. The same error pops up.